# Pandas groupby and Max value

Tags: pandas, max

I'm trying to get the highest amount for each group using the Pandas library.

An additional condition is to obtain the maximum amount compared to data from 180 days prior to the date in the DATE column.

Below is the data frame I have.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'num': ["50110-374","50110-374","50110-374","50110-374","50110-374","50110-374","50110-374","50110-374","50110-374","50110-374","50110-3421","50110-3421","50110-3421","50110-3421","50110-3421","50110-3421","50110-3421"],
                   'date': ["2017-11-24","2018-02-08","2018-03-08","2018-03-17","2018-04-11","2018-04-16","2018-05-05","2018-06-04","2018-06-16","2018-07-13","2019-01-28","2019-02-10","2019-03-16","2019-03-16","2019-06-07","2019-06-30", "2022-06-30"],
                   'type':["39","39","39","39","39","39","39","39","39","39","73","73","73","73","73","73","73"],
                   'price':[17000,12500,14000,14000,18000,13000,14250,15000,12900,15000,35500,34500,35000,37000,33300,34800, 32000]})`
```

```
`    num        date       type price
0   50110-374   2017-11-24  39  17000
1   50110-374   2018-02-08  39  12500
2   50110-374   2018-03-08  39  14000
3   50110-374   2018-03-17  39  14000
4   50110-374   2018-04-11  39  18000
5   50110-374   2018-04-16  39  13000
6   50110-374   2018-05-05  39  14250
7   50110-374   2018-06-04  39  15000
8   50110-374   2018-06-16  39  12900
9   50110-374   2018-07-13  39  15000
10  50110-3421  2019-01-28  73  35500
11  50110-3421  2019-02-10  73  34500
12  50110-3421  2019-03-16  73  35000
13  50110-3421  2019-03-16  73  37000
14  50110-3421  2019-06-07  73  33300
15  50110-3421  2019-06-30  73  34800
16  50110-3421  2022-06-30  73  32000`
```

Below is the desired MAX column as a result.

I wish 'max' columns like this.

(index 16 max value is 32000 due to 180 days calculation)

```
`   num         date        type price  max
0   50110-374   2017-11-24  39  17000   NaN
1   50110-374   2018-02-08  39  12500   17000.0
2   50110-374   2018-03-08  39  14000   17000.0
3   50110-374   2018-03-17  39  14000   17000.0
4   50110-374   2018-04-11  39  18000   18000.0
5   50110-374   2018-04-16  39  13000   18000.0
6   50110-374   2018-05-05  39  14250   18000.0
7   50110-374   2018-06-04  39  15000   18000.0
8   50110-374   2018-06-16  39  12900   18000.0
9   50110-374   2018-07-13  39  15000   18000.0
10  50110-3421  2019-01-28  73  35500   NaN
11  50110-3421  2019-02-10  73  34500   35500.0
12  50110-3421  2019-03-16  73  35000   35500.0
13  50110-3421  2019-03-16  73  37000   37000.0
14  50110-3421  2019-06-07  73  33300   37000.0
15  50110-3421  2019-06-30  73  34800   37000.0
16  50110-3421  2022-06-30  73  32000   32000.0`
```

Thank you for reading it.

I tryed this function. It worked, but working time too long.

```
def maxDeal(date):
    testDate = date
    dateIndex = totalMonthList.index(testDate)
    testRange = totalMonthList[dateIndex-720:dateIndex+1]
    
    tmpCdDf = priceApi[priceApi['date'] == testDate][['num','type','date']]
    tmpCdLst = list(tmpCdDf['num'].drop_duplicates())
    maxDf = df[(df['num'].isin(tmpCdLst)) & (df['date'].isin(testRange))].groupby(['date','type'])['price'].max().reset_index()
    tmpCdDf = pd.merge(tmpCdDf,maxDf, how='left', on=['num','type'] )
    maxValue = list(tmpCdDf['price'])
    df.loc[df['date'] == date, 'max'] = maxValue
```

Comment: why `row0` 's max is NaN? in `row4` , you find max value include own price `18000`

Comment: sorry, my mistake.   row 0 max value is 17000 and row 10 max value is 35500.  not +- 180days, -180days

Comment: it's a mistake, why not edit question? And `row12` and `row13` have same date. Is it intended? If it is intentional, is their max value set correctly?

Comment: I tried edit, but edit page cannot open ( "Approve, reject, or improve this suggested edit." msg pop up). row12 and row 13 date is correct.  but row 12 data will be 37000,, not 35500.  I'm so sorry ...

Comment: ok i see. i will slove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step1**

change date column to datetime and make `+ 180d series`

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
s = df['date'] + pd.Timedelta('180d')
```

**Step2**

`apply` apply function by `row`, when axis=1

make condition & `apply` `where` func and find max

condition:

1. index must be less or equal than index of `row`
2. date + 180d must be less or equal than date of `row`
3. type is same with  type of `row`

```
df.apply(lambda x: df['price'].where((df.index <= x.name) & s.ge(x['date']) & df['type'].eq(x['type'])).max(), axis=1)
```

`result`

```
0     17000.0
1     17000.0
2     17000.0
3     17000.0
4     18000.0
5     18000.0
6     18000.0
7     18000.0
8     18000.0
9     18000.0
10    35500.0
11    35500.0
12    35500.0
13    37000.0
14    37000.0
15    37000.0
16    32000.0
dtype: float64
```

**Step3**

make result to `max` column

```
df['max'] = df.apply(lambda x: df['price'].where((df.index <= x.name) & s.ge(x['date']) & df['type'].eq(x['type'])).max(), axis=1)
```

`df`

```
    num         date       type price   max
0   50110-374   2017-11-24  39  17000   17000.0
1   50110-374   2018-02-08  39  12500   17000.0
2   50110-374   2018-03-08  39  14000   17000.0
3   50110-374   2018-03-17  39  14000   17000.0
4   50110-374   2018-04-11  39  18000   18000.0
5   50110-374   2018-04-16  39  13000   18000.0
6   50110-374   2018-05-05  39  14250   18000.0
7   50110-374   2018-06-04  39  15000   18000.0
8   50110-374   2018-06-16  39  12900   18000.0
9   50110-374   2018-07-13  39  15000   18000.0
10  50110-3421  2019-01-28  73  35500   35500.0
11  50110-3421  2019-02-10  73  34500   35500.0
12  50110-3421  2019-03-16  73  35000   35500.0
13  50110-3421  2019-03-16  73  37000   37000.0
14  50110-3421  2019-06-07  73  33300   37000.0
15  50110-3421  2019-06-30  73  34800   37000.0
16  50110-3421  2022-06-30  73  32000   32000.0
```

**Full Code**

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
s = df['date'] + pd.Timedelta('180d')
df['max'] = df.apply(lambda x: df['price'].where((df.index <= x.name) & s.ge(x['date']) & df['type'].eq(x['type'])).max(), axis=1)
```

Comment: It worked perpectly. Thank  you so much.   But It's a little disappointing that the speed hasn't improved,,  (my dataframe is 4549285 rows × 6 columns)  I tried your recommend code, it takes 25 min over.   But I appriciate your simple and powerful code.  I watched your youTube a few minute ago. And very  impressed your lesson. Thank you.   (답변 정말 감사드립니다 ^^)

Comment: I thought it would take time because loop(`apply`), but it took longer than I thought. I will think way to improve.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to Use groupby + transform:

```py
df["max"] = df.groupby('num')["price"].transform('max')
```

Comment: I want get Max value in specific date period (from column date to 180day ago)